# Failed to get response of 200 array items, but getting 50 array items works

Tags: android, android-volley

When I am fetching array items from server using volley String request, I am not getting 200 items in array. But I see the same response in Postman. I cannot get any response from volley.

I fetch 50 items when array length is 50. But when array length is 200, I cannot get any response from volley using post method.

Comment: wellcome to SO..please attach your code with the post

Comment: You have to give more details. For example add the code where you mean you fetch 50 items and where not. Try to give the array you are trying to process. Besides you should use the code delimiter only for codes and code lines. Happy coding.

Comment: It sounds like there is something wrong with your post call (if it works ok in postman), do you need headers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use https://github.com/firminApp/EasyRequestMaker this instead of Volley while you work with a large amount of date. I had worked with it it's working perfectly in one of my project

Comment: i want to put parameter inside hasmap how to put using EasyRequestMaker

Comment: There you will find the example if you not get it then let me know I will give to example